# How to use Brave web browser with Selenium on Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, macos-catalina, brave-browser

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+selenium+brave+browser

I see this example to use brave browser on windows. Is it supposed to work on Catalina as well by just replacing driver_path and brave_path?

Also, Chromedriver is only for Chrome. How to determine which version of chromedriver should be used for brave browser?

https://chromedriver.chromium.org

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
# option.add_argument("--incognito") OPTIONAL
# option.add_argument("--headless") OPTIONAL

# Create new Instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prerequisites:
Your `chromedriver` version should match your `Brave Browser` web driver version.

To make sure it does:

- Check `ChromeDriver` version with `brew info chromedriver`. Along the lines of the output it should read `chromedriver: 89.0.4389.23` (latest version as of writing this post)
- Open `Brave Browser`, in menu bar click `Brave` -> `About Brave`. Along the lines it should read `Version 1.22.71 Chromium: 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)` (again, latest as of writing this post)
- These two should match, however, i am not entirely sure to which degree, since, as you can see here, last entries (`.23` and `.114`) don't match, yet this works perfectly fine on my machine (`macOS Big Sur 11.2.3`) I don't think macOS version should really matter, but i still mentioned it for the sake of completeness.

Finally run the following code (replace paths with ones on your machine if they are different):

```
from selenium import webdriver  
driverPath = '/usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/89.0.4389.23/chromedriver'
binaryPath = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = binaryPath
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverPath, chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://www.google.es")
```

If you have never used `chromedriver` before, after  runnning the code you should see a macOS prompt saying that `chromedriver` is from unknown developer or was downloaded from the internet, smth like that. Close  that prompt (It's important that you do this before moving on). Then go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> press the lock icon and unlock it and then approve `chromedriver` to run on your machine. Run the above code again, a new macOS prompt will appear saying smth about unknown developer again, this time you can just click Open. Brave Browser window should pop up at this point. At least it did on my machine.
P.S. I apologise for possibly going into too much detail, but sometimes i get really frustrated with answers which skip parts which are considered to be ***obvious***

Comment: chrome_options=options gives a DeprecationWarning. options=options should be used in this example. Please update your answer and I vote it up again. Your answer is very helpful, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the next person looking, this is the most current way of using Brave with Selenium on Mac:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driverPath = "/Applications/chromedriver" # Path to ChromeDriver
service = Service(driverPath)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser" # Path to Brave Browser (this is the default)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# From here its Selenium as usual, example:
driver.get("https://google.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```